# C# Create group boxes dynamically depending on data received in Windows Forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently working on windows forms application, and I want to dynamically create form, which creates GroupBox depending on categories and products. 
I have two tables like:

```
+-------------------------------+
|           Category            |
+-------------------------------+
| CategoryId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) |
| Name (VARCHAR(255))           |
| CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255))       |
| CreationDate(DATETIME)        |
+-------------------------------+


+-----------------------------+
|           Product           |
+-----------------------------+
| ProductId(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER) |
| CategoryId (FK)             |
| Name(VARCHAR(255))          |
| CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255))     |
| CreationDate(DATETIME)      |
| IsDeleted(BOOL)             |
+-----------------------------+
```

For example if I have category `Fruit` and its products are `Banana` and `Apple`, but I have another category called `Vegetables` and its products are `Avocado` and `Tomato` like:

```
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
|    CategoryId (UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)     | Name (VARCHAR(255)) | CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255)) | CreationDate(DATETIME) |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| CEF50872-B8E7-4EA0-A3D7-00048FFC82DA | Fruit               | Test                    | 10/11/2018             |
| 646B5A64-EA28-4471-8964-0017EB511797 | Vegetables          | Test                    | 10/12/2018             |
+--------------------------------------+---------------------+-------------------------+------------------------+


+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
|     ProductId(UNIQUEIDENTIFIER)      |           CategoryId (FK)            |  Name   | CreatedBy(VARCHAR(255)) | CreationDate(DATETIME) |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
| D81EFF8C-9B8D-48C9-9CC7-0015B2787D4A | CEF50872-B8E7-4EA0-A3D7-00048FFC82DA | Banana  | Test                    | 10/11/2018             |
| 7683554C-5E46-40FE-9285-001E8CD67740 | CEF50872-B8E7-4EA0-A3D7-00048FFC82DA | Apple   | Test                    | 10/11/2018             |
| 614FBE96-6355-4C3B-985B-002E2B9853CB | 646B5A64-EA28-4471-8964-0017EB511797 | Avocado | Test                    | 10/11/2018             |
| 74352B1B-36E8-4913-898E-002ED4CB21AD | 646B5A64-EA28-4471-8964-0017EB511797 | Tomato  | Test                    | 10/11/2018             |
+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------------+---------+-------------------------+------------------------+
```

When I receive that info in `c#` from stored procedure like

```
SELECT * FROM Category AS c
INNER JOIN Product AS P ON C.CategoryId = P.CategoryId
```

So, I want to create `groupbox` dynamically. How can I create this `groupbox` depending on categories and their products? Regards

At the final I want something like this:
[image]

**Update**

I try as comments bellow like:

Receive data from datatable:

```
  var data = db.GetTableBySQL("usp_RedMarks_Get");

    foreach (DataRow itm in data.Rows)
    {
        if (itm["CategoryName"].ToString() != CurrentGroupBoxName)
        {
            flpRedMarks.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox(itm, 200, 100));
        }
    }
```

Create GroupBox and items:

```
 private GroupBox GetGroupBox(DataRow c, int width, int height)
        {
            GroupBox currentGroupBox = new GroupBox();
            currentGroupBox.Size = new Size(width, height);
            currentGroupBox.Text = c["CategoryName"].ToString();
            currentGroupBox.Name = c["CategoryName"].ToString();
            CurrentGroupBoxName = currentGroupBox.Name;

            var y = 20;
            foreach (var itm in c.Table.Rows)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Text = itm.ToString();
                cb.Location = new Point(5, y);
                // you can add an event here...
                //cb.CheckedChanged += cb_SomeEvent;
                currentGroupBox.Controls.Add(cb);
                y += 20;
            }

            return currentGroupBox;
        }
```

I receive data from SQL like:

[image]

But instead of get items(products) based in categories I get merged data:
[image]

What am I doing wrong? Regards

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Looping through the categories? Creating group boxes? Adding items to them?

Comment: In c#, I don't know how to group products in their category and how to create groupbox to create structure: Category = GroupBox (text and Name), and Products inside this groupbox @DStanley

Comment: You will probably be better off using a dynamic control like a [`DataGridView`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridview?view=netframework-4.7.1).

Comment: The final use of this is, each product has a checkbox, so that's why I want as group box, I upload a picture on my question to be more clear @DourHighArch

Comment: @Jonathan. I updated the code in my answer to better fit your updated question. The issue here is that your calling `GetGroupBox()` four times and in each of those calls your looping through all eight rows of the results you get back. And the labels you see are wrong because your getting the subcategory name with `itm.ToString()` instead of using `itm["SubcategoryName"].ToString()`. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use `flowLayoutPanel` control to make the spacing for the groupboxes.
Then you can write a logic that will create your `groupbox` elements dynamically.

Here is one way to achieve this task:

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication47
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var dataFromDb = GetData();
            foreach (var itm in dataFromDb)
            {
                flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox(itm, 200, 100));
            }
        }

        private GroupBox GetGroupBox(Category c,int width,int height)
        {
            GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
            g.Size = new Size(width, height);
            g.Text = c.Name;

            var y = 20;
            foreach (var itm in c.Items)
            {
                CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
                cb.Text = itm;
                cb.Location = new Point(5, y);
                // you can add an event here...
                cb.CheckedChanged += cb_SomeEvent;
                g.Controls.Add(cb);
                y += 20;
            }

            return g;
        }

        private void cb_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        private List<Category> GetData()
        {
            // Just to simulate a database...
            Category c1 = new Category("Fruit", new List<string>() { "Banana", "Apple" });
            Category c2 = new Category("Vegetables", new List<string>() { "Avocado", "Tomato" });
            Category c3 = new Category("Programming Languages", new List<string>() { "C#", "Visual Basic" });
            Category c4 = new Category("Stars", new List<string>() { "Venus", "Mars" });

            List<Category> result = new List<Category>();
            result.Add(c1);
            result.Add(c2);
            result.Add(c3);
            result.Add(c4);

            return result;
        }
    }

    class Category
    {
        public string Name;
        public List<string> Items;

        public Category(string name,List<string> items)
        {
            this.Name = name;
            this.Items = items;
        }
    }
}
```

**GUI OUTPUT:**

[image]

**UPDATE:**

For OP's request, here is one way to achieve this **without** using `List<T>`.

In this example we are iterating straightforwardly on the `DataTable` (after we extracted the categories distinctly) and extracting the matched sub categories for each category using [LINQ](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/linq/).

Please see comments inside the code:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dataFromDb = GetData();
    // extract distinct categories into an array - for each group box
    string[] distinctCetgories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable()
        .Select(x => x.Field<string>("CategoryName")).Distinct().ToArray();

    // iterate on the distinct categories
    foreach(var itm in distinctCetgories)
    {
        // extract all the subcategories for the checkboxes inside the groupbox
        string[] subcategories = dataFromDb.AsEnumerable().
            Where(x => x.Field<string>("SubCategoryName") == itm).
            Select(y => y.Field<string>("SubCategoryName")).ToArray();

        flowLayoutPanel1.Controls.Add(GetGroupBox(itm,subcategories, 200, 100));
    }
}

private GroupBox GetGroupBox(string categoryName,string[] subCategories,int width, int 
{
    GroupBox g = new GroupBox();
    g.Size = new Size(width, height);
    g.Text = categoryName;

    var y = 20;

    foreach (var itm in subCategories)
    {
        CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
        cb.Text = itm;
        cb.Location = new Point(5, y);
        // you can add an event here...
        cb.CheckedChanged += cb_SomeEvent;
        g.Controls.Add(cb);
        y += 20;
    }

    return g;
}

private void cb_SomeEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    // return datadata using your query:
    // SELECT* FROM Category AS c
    // INNER JOIN Product AS P ON C.CategoryId = P.CategoryId
    // ..... create datatable ......
    return new DataTable();
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use Datatable instead a List? so how can I specified from datatable this products are from this category?

Comment: Yes, just itterate on the datatable like you itterate on the list. If you want an example i can uodate tommorow.

Comment: I really appreciate it.. I already updated my question with my issue using DataTable

Comment: @Jonathan i have updated my answer with a suggestion to do it directly with the `datatable`. please see the "UPDATE" section.

Answer (score 2):

If you can add and ORDER BY clause to your stored procedure like this:

```
SELECT C.Name AS 'CategoryName', P.Name AS 'SubcategoryName'
FROM Category AS C
INNER JOIN Product AS P ON C.CategoryId = P.CategoryId
ORDER BY C.Name
```

You can then iterate through the DataRows you get back like below. Note that I'm adding a flow panel inside the group box to avoid the need to keep an offset variable.

```
GroupBox currentGroupBox = new GroupBox();
FlowLayoutPanel currentGroupBoxPanel = null;
foreach (DataRow itm in _data.Rows)
{
    var currentCategoryName = itm["CategoryName"].ToString();
    if (currentCategoryName != currentGroupBox.Name)
    {
        currentGroupBox = new GroupBox();
        currentGroupBox.Name = currentCategoryName;
        currentGroupBoxPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();
        currentGroupBoxPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        currentGroupBoxPanel.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        currentGroupBox.Controls.Add(currentGroupBoxPanel);
        flpRedMarks.Controls.Add(currentGroupBox);
    }
    var cb = new CheckBox();
    cb.Text = itm["SubcategoryName"].ToString();
    currentGroupBoxPanel.Controls.Add(cb);
}
```

Comment: It seems that it works , I test later and mark as correct answer if it works , thank you so much and Marry Christmas!